# use hbase to export/import a table data between two clusters, The size of two tables and the number of rows are inconsistent

Tags: import, export, hbase

The first table size is 10G with 8 million rows, but imported table size is 8G with 6 million rows. Why is there so much less data?

Comment: did the source table had same number of rows (8M) when you started the export or was it  updated while export was in progress? Does your export has 10 M records?

Comment: yes,the problem is in the process of exporting, and the amount of data is reduced when exporting.Why does the amount of data become less when exporting?